# Wanted a failing test case for code for Subset with maximum sum so that no two elements in it are adjacent to each other

Tags: python-3.x

Given a multi-set of non-zero integers find a multi-subset of integers with maximum sum such that no two elements in this multi-subset are adjacent to each other. If there are at least two such multi-subsets then that multi-subset is chosen whose smallest element is the largest of all smallest elements in the candidate multi-subsets.

**I saw solutions for finding the maximum sum, but I want the actual multi-subset too. Also, I don't want code; I just want a failing test case for my code.**

Input is in the following format.

```
T positive integer (# of test cases)
N1 (positive integer followed by N1 integers representing the set whose "maximum sum" subset has to be identified)
a1 a2 a3 ... aN1
N2
...
NT
....
```

Output
`a3a1`  (required subset in reverse order - for example, a1 + a3 forms the largest sum in the first set above and so output is a3a1)

Concrete examples:

```
2
4
3 6 2 -2
4
4 5 3 4
```

Output

```
6
45
```

({4,4} and {3,5} both form the largest sum but 35 is not output because smallest element in {4,4} > smallest element in {5,3})

I wrote code and it passes on all test cases I can think of. But it fails a formal assessment and I don't know what the failing test cases are. My idea is the following. Either the first element F in the set is a member of the required subset or it is not. If it is, then we recursively find the "minimum sum" subset from the third element onwards in the original set and adjoin it to F. If it is not, then we recursively find this subset from the second element onwards of the original set.

Below is the code I wrote. Can someone give a failing test case?

```
#returns 1 if all but the first element are negative
def all_neg(t):
    sum=0
    for i in range(1,len(t)):
        if t[i]<0:
            sum+=1
    if sum==len(t)-1:
        return 1

#reverses string
def reverse(t):
  if len(t)<=1:
      return t
  else:
      l=[t[-1]]
      l.extend(reverse(t[:-1]))
      return l

def max(a1,a2):
  if a1>a2:
    return a1
  else:
    return a2

#returns the sum of the subset with the maximum sum
def sum_max(t):
    if len(t)==0: 
     return 0
    elif len(t)==1:
     return (t[0])
    elif len(t)==2:
     if t[0]>t[1]:
        return t[0]
     else:
        return t[1]
    else:  
        if t[0]>0:
            if sum_max(t[2:])>0:
              c1=t[0]+sum_max(t[2:])
            else:
              c1=t[0]
        else:
           return sum_max(t[1:])
        c2=sum_max(t[1:])
        return(max(c1,c2))


#returns the subset with the maximum sum
def arr_max(t):
  if len(t)<=1:
    return t
  elif len(t)==2:
    if t[0]>t[1]:
        return [t[0]]
    else:
        return [t[1]]
  elif sum_max(t)>sum_max(t[1:]):
      if all_neg(t[1:]):
          return([t[0]])

      l=[]
      l.append(t[0])
      tmp=arr_max(t[2:])
      l.extend(arr_max(t[2:]))

      return l
  elif sum_max(t)==sum_max(t[1:]):
      l=[]

      if (t[0]<0):
          return arr_max(t[1:])
      l.append(t[0])
      l.extend(arr_max(t[2:]))
      m=arr_max(t[1:])
      sl=sum(l)
      sm=sum(m)
      if sl>sm:
          return l
      elif sm>sl:
          return m
      lm=min(l)
      mm=min(m)
      if lm<mm:
       return m
      else:
       return l
  else:
    return arr_max(t[1:])

def main():
    test=int(input())
    for i in range(0,test):
        N=int(input())
        t=[int(s) for s in input().split()]
        y=arr_max(t)

        print(''.join(str(i) for i in reverse(y))) 

main()
```

Comment: The actual output of your code has two lines per test case eg. `y= [1]` and
`1`. Does that match the requirements/instructions of the assignment?

Comment: I removed the y=[1]. I had forgotten to remove it from the above version but it was not there in the version I submitted for assessment. Thank you.

Comment: Your code outputs `221` for input `1 2 2 2 2` which is incorrect. Also, the output for `4 5 3 4` should be `54` (maximum sum is 9 not 8).

Comment: Why do you say 221 is incorrect? What is the correct answer according to you? Also, I corrected the output in the question for 4 5 3 4 - changed it from 44 to 45. Thank you for pointing it out. The code does output 45.

Comment: By definition a set is a collection of unique elements. `221` has duplicate elements. If you're working with sets it's not the same as working with arrays/lists.

Comment: Thank you. I want a multi subset. I corrected the question.